# Find $0<a_i<1,a_i\in\mathbb Q$ such that $\sum\arctan a_i=\pi/4$.

Tags: trigonometry

> Does there exist $0<a_i<1,a_i\in\mathbb Q,i=1,...,6$ such that $\sum^6_{i=1}\arctan a_i=\pi/4$? Please give an example if "yes".

I don't see any reason that there cannot be, but I cannot give an explicit example. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

We prove by induction that, for any $n\ge 2$, $\gamma\in\mathbb Q_{>0}$, there exists some $\theta_i\in(0,\pi/4)$ such that $\tan\theta_i\in\mathbb Q$, $\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i<\pi/2$ and $\tan\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_i=\gamma$. Taking $a_i=\tan\theta_i$ in the particular case $n=6,\gamma=1$ yields what we need in the original question.

For $n=2$, it suffices to find $u,v\in(0,1)\cap\mathbb Q$ such that $u+v=\gamma(1-uv)$. This is rather obvious: just take any $u\in\bigg((\gamma-1)/(\gamma +1), \gamma\bigg)\cap(0,1)\cap\mathbb Q$(easy to check this set is non-empty), and $v=(\gamma-u)/(\gamma u+1)$. Now put $\theta_1=\arctan u$, $\theta_2 = \arctan v$.

Suppose we've proved the assertion for $n\le k$. For $n=k+1$, by induction hypothesis there exists some $\varphi_1,\varphi_2\in(0,\pi/4)$ such that $\tan\varphi_1,\tan\varphi_2\in\mathbb Q$ and $\tan(\varphi_1+\varphi_2)=\gamma$. Again by induction hypothesis there exists some $\theta_i\in(0,\pi/4)$ such that $\tan\theta_i\in\mathbb Q$, $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\theta_i<\pi/2$, and $\tan\sum_{i=1}^k\theta_i = \tan\varphi_1$. But $\tan x$ is monotone on $(0,\pi/2)$, hence $\sum_{i=1}^k \theta_i=\varphi_1$. Putting $\theta_{k+1}=\varphi_2$, we've proved the assertion for $n=k+1$.